# Strange titanium error BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium

I am starting to get this error:

BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting same error during download a mp4 file from server in iOS

Comment: I'm getting the same when trying to load an image via URL retrieved from an API call.